# Android how load n TextViews with data from Sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I have an sqlite db that contains information for some TextViews, like text, background color and id of the changed TextView, because I have a TableView with 60 TextViews.
When the user touch one of them, he can change the content of the TextView and the background color.
My problem is that when I take back all the saved TextView I put them into a list.

Materia.java is my object

```
package com.ddz.diarioscolastico;

public class Materia {

private int _id;
private String _nome;
private int _colore;
//private int _giorno;
//private int _ora;

//Empty constructor
public Materia(){

}
//Constructor
public Materia(int id, String nome, int colore){
    this._id = id;
    this._nome = nome;
    this._colore = colore;

}
// constructor
public Materia(String nome, int colore){
    this._nome = nome;
    this._colore = colore;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

//getting color
public int getColor(){

    return this._colore;

}
//setting color
public void setColor(int colore){

    this._colore = colore;

}
//getting nome materia
public String getMateria() {

    return this._nome;

}
//setting nome materia
 public void setMateria(String nome) {

     this._nome = nome;

 }
}
```

With the class MySQLiteHelper, I manage the database:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//Database name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "materie.db";
//Materie table name
public static final String TABLE_MATERIE = "materie";
//Materie columns table names
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "nome";
public static final String COLUMN_COLOR = "colore";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_MATERIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MATERIE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_COLOR + " INTEGER," + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MATERIE_TABLE);
}
// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MATERIE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new contact
public void addMateria(Materia materia) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, materia.getMateria()); // Materia Name
    values.put(COLUMN_COLOR, materia.getColor()); // Materia color

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_MATERIE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
public Materia getMateria(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    //ELIMINATO COLUMN_DAY e COLUMN_HOUR
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MATERIE, new String[] { COLUMN_ID,
                    COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_COLOR }, COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Materia materia = new Materia(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    // return contact
    return materia;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Materia> getAllMaterie() {
    List<Materia> materiaList = new ArrayList<Materia>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MATERIE;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Materia materia = new Materia();
            materia.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            materia.setMateria(cursor.getString(1));
            materia.setColor(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            // Adding contact to list
           materiaList.add(materia);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return materiaList;
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getMateriaCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MATERIE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateMateria(Materia materia) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, materia.getMateria());
    values.put(COLUMN_COLOR, materia.getColor());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_MATERIE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(materia.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteMateria(Materia materia) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_MATERIE, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(materia.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

}//Close class database
```

As you can see with the method  `public List<Materia> getAllMaterie()`, I take all materiel from sqlite and put them into a list.

`onCreate` of the activity that manages data:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);

    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    //Get all materie inside database
    List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
    for (Materia mat : materia) {
        //Change with loop all changed TextView into database by id
        TextView changedtextview = (TextView) findViewById(mat.getID());
        changedtextview.setText(mat.getMateria());
    }


}//Fine oncreate
```

In my Activity, I need to take back all the materia inputted into the database for changing the `TextView`s that are touched from user.
How can I take the single id's in the List materia?
Something like:

```
 TextView changedtextview = (TextView)findViewById(materia._id);
```

But this is not working.
There is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing

```
List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
```

you just create and fill the collection of your objects. To display this collection (the list) you should use a ListView in conjunction with some adapter like ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. Adapter usually has a method `getView()` which is responsible for filling the list item (a cell) with desired data. And I can't see any ListView or adatpter in your code.

Comment: ok, i'm not sure if i understand you.
I change the TextView touched from the id that are stored into database.
But i don't know how access to the single field of the object materia.
The list<Materia> materia is a list of object, right?
So, can i access to the single field? like `id = materia.id`
Or for do this i need the getView() that you write on your answer?
Can you post some code so i can understand what you mean??

Comment: If you have a list of your Materie objects so there is an object you are looking for inside this collection, right? So just find the object you need and obtain all the desired info from it. Iterate the collection to find the target object you need. When you will found target object you could access its data like you mentioned, like id = materia.id.

Comment: Ah, you don't understand that `TextView` has absolutely no connection with text you store in sql db. You can't store VIEW things but you store only some data you can get from `View`. Like a `String` from `TextView` using `textView.getText()` or the color of the text of textview. You can't store visual part. There is no any TextView in you List of Materie. TextView is a part of a layout. Then you write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);` this means the layout file `activity_set_orario.xml` could contain some `TextViews` so you could find that `TextView` using `findViewById()`.

Comment: Ok, now i try to iterate this list and see if Android studio say to me Cannot resolve!
For your second comment, sorry i don't post the code of the xml, yes i have 60 textview into the xml so i can take back them by the id stored to the database.
Thank you for your answere. i edited with new code can you tell me if it's right?
Or some suggestion for iterate objects.

Comment: Iteration part looks good. You are looking for needed TextView and setting its text to it. If mat.getID() really corresponds to a real id of a TextView in the activity_set_orario.xml it should work ok. Set the color of the text the same way like you set the text.

Comment: I added the first item, and at the next start of the `onCreate` method the app crash with this report error to the log:` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ddz.diarioscolastico/com.ddz.diarioscolastico.ActivitySetOrario} Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`
Do you know why??

Comment: Probably it can't find a TextView with given id (returned from `mat.getID()` I beleive). Maybe `mat.getID()` returns 0 or other int of unexisting TextView. Try to check `changedtextview` for `null` before working with it.

Comment: Yes i had a record with null id so the app crash, i must uninstall the app, and reinstall so i have a new database with correct information.
Thank you Stan.